# Set Expiration of Provisioning Profile

Tags: ios, security, provisioning, ios-provisioning

Is it possible to set the expiration date of a Provisioning Profile?  I am having an internal trial within the company and I would like to set the `expiration` date to be the end of the trial; instead of just being a year from the `creation` date.  Is it possible or is it always going to be one year from the `creation` date?

Also, if its not possible to set the `expiration` date, is it possible to kill the provisioning profile from the portal that way the application itself will expire and not be able to be opened?  Or am I better off just coding something up that will not allow the app to be opened after a certain date?

If it matters, the trial is going to be a small 5-10 person trial in marketing.  The devices are either iPad 2s or the iPhone 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app profile will last for 3 months on the device. It's not changeable and cannot be edited. Once a device has your profile, it's done. You can remove that profile from the device or the app itself. If it's only an app which your company will use, i advise you to create some kind of validation yourself. A code inside your app or even a web service that you will fetch the valid devices.